# Can a diagonal matrix generally be made with two independent linear transforms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Alright, so assuming that $A$ is an invertible, non-diagonalisable matrix in $V = \mathbb{R}^n$. Can this matrix when multiplied with two independent invertible matrices be made diagonal? I.e., do there exist invertible matrices $T_1,T_2$ such that:

$$
T_1 A T_2 = D,
$$

where $D$ refers to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can let $T_1=A^{-1}$ and let $T_2=I$, this will make $D=I$ which is a diagonal matrix.